# Extracting multiple fields from a JSON in python

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON object:

```js
{
  'organisations': {
    'total-items': '41477',
    'organisation': [
      {
        'mappings': None,
        'active-request': 'false',
        'identifiers': {
          'identifier': {
            'code': 'ORG-100023310',
            'code-system': '100000167446',
            'code-system-name': ' OMS Organization Identifier'
          }
        },
        'name': 'advanceCOR GmbH',
        'operational-attributes': {
          'created-on': '2016-10-18T15:38:34.322+02:00',
          'modified-on': '2022-11-02T08:23:13.989+01:00'
        },
        'locations': {
          'location': [
            {
              'location-id': {
                'link': {
                  'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100052061'
                },
                'id': 'LOC-100052061'
              }
            },
            {
              'location-id': {
                'link': {
                  'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100032442'
                },
                'id ': 'LOC-100032442'
              }
            },
            {
              'location-id': {
                'link': {
                  'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100042003'
                },
                'id': 'LOC-100042003'
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        'organisation-id': {
          'link': {
            'rel': 'self',
            'href': 'https://v1 /organisations/ORG-100023310'
          },
          'id': 'ORG-100023310'
        },
        'status': 'ACTIVE'
      },
      {
        'mappings': None,
        'active-request': 'false',
        'identifiers': {
          'identifier': {
            'code': 'ORG-100004261',
            'code-system': '100000167446',
            'code-system-name': 'OMS organization Identifier'
          }
        },
        'name': 'Beacon Pharmaceuticals Limited',
        'operational-attributes': {
          'created-on': '2016-10-18T14:48:16.293+02:00',
          'modified-on': '2022-10-12T08:26:24.645+02:00'
        },
        'locations': {
          'location': [
            {
              'location-id': {
                'link': {
                  'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100005615'
                },
                'id': 'LOC-100005615'
              }
            },
            {
              'location-id': {
                'link': {
                  'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100000912'
                },
                'id': 'LOC-100000912'
              }
            },
            {
              'location-id': {
                'link': {
                  'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100043831'
                },
                'id': 'LOC-100043831'
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        'organisation-id': {
          'link': {
            'rel': 'self',
            'href': 'https://v1/organisations/ORG-100004261'
          },
          'id': 'ORG-100004261'
        },
        'status': 'ACTIVE'
      },
```

I would like to fetch following fields 'code, name, location, status' for all the org_id        (type of d: class 'list', type of d[0) is class 'dict'. I am using following lines of code however could not fetch all the organisation ids and location_id (only 1 I can get)  (shown in current output). How can I get information for all the org_id (shown in expected output)?

Code:

```
with open('organisations.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    print (d[0]['organisations']['organisation'][2]['identifiers']['identifier']['code'])   #code
    print (d[0]['organisations']['organisation'][2]['name'])                                #name
    print (d[0]['organisations']['organisation'][2]['locations'])                       #location
    print (d[0]['organisations']['organisation'][2]['status'])                          #status
```

current output:

```
ORG-100023310
advanceCOR GmbH
{'location': {'location-id': {'link': {'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100052061'}, 'id': ' LOC-100052061'}}}
ACTIVE
```

Expected output:

```
org_id        org_name                         location_id                                  status
ORG-100023310 advanceCOR GmbH                  LOC-100052061, LOC-100032442, LOC-100042003  ACTIVE
ORG-100004261 Beacon Pharmaceuticals Limited   LOC-100005615, LOC-100000912, LOC-100043831         ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt has two flaws; as others have pointed out, you are only extracting the last item by hardcoding `['organisation'][2]`, and you are not doing anything to serialize the dictionary of locations into a string.

Here is a modified version of your code which produces the desired output.

```
import json

fmt = "{0:14}{1:33}{2:45}{3}"
print(fmt.format("org_id", "org_name", "location_id", "status"))

with open('organisations.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    for org in d['organisations']['organisation']:
        locations = ", ".join(loc['location-id']['id'] for loc in org['locations']['location'])
        print(fmt.format(
            org['identifiers']['identifier']['code'],
            org['name'], locations, org['status']))
```

The "JSON" sample you posted was not really valid JSON, so I had to make some changes to it for the code to work.

If you are new to Python, you might want to avoid the dictionary comprehension `loc['location-id']['id'] for loc in org['locations']['location']` in favor of its longhand articulation:

```
locations = []
for loc in org['locations']['location']:
    locations.append(loc['location-id']['id'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However when I run it on whole file. After few lines of correct output, I get following error. It is due to some issue in the data. Could you help in fixing that ` TypeError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [274] , in <cell line: 12> () 
     18  for loc in org[ ' locations ' ][ ' location ' ]:
      19      print ( type (loc))
 ---> 20      print ( loc [ ' location -id ' ] [ ' id ' ])

TypeError : string indices must be integers`

Comment: I checked, type(loc) is <class 'dict'> and after 3 correct org_ids and their locations.. It is <class 'str'>

Comment: One of the samples in your (not really) JSON had `"id ":` instead of `"id":` (notice the space). I assumed that was a spurious formatting error. If that's not the problematic one, try running the input through an online JSON validator

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to loop through all your organization,

```py
with open('organisations.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

    # assuming above code is your working code
    # assign organization list in a variable
    organization_list = d[0]['organisations']['organisation']

    # now loop through that list
    for organization in organization_list:
        name = organization['name']
        # fetch other values similary

        # print the values here
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only 1 row as output because you are printing only index 2. Hope the following will be helpful.

```
with open('data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    
result = pd.DataFrame( columns=['org_id', 'org_name', "location_id", "status"])
organizations = data['organisations']['organisation']
for organization in organizations:
    record = {
        'org_id': organization['identifiers']['identifier']['code'],
        'org_name': organization['name'],
        'location_id': organization['locations'],
        'status': organization['status']
    }
    result_row = pd.DataFrame.from_records([record])
    result = pd.concat([result, result_row])
print(result)
```

Comment: Using Pandas for convenience is fine if you are already using it for other reasons anyway; but having a newbie install Pandas when it's not strictly necessary is massive overkill (and your answer doesn't even explain where `pd` is supposed to come from).

Answer (score 0):

The following extracts the information for both organizations.

```
import json

with open('organisations.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    
    for organisation in d['organisations']['organisation']:
        print(organisation['identifiers']['identifier']['code'])    #code
        print(organisation['name'])                                 #name
        print(organisation['locations']['location'])                #location
        print(organisation['status'])                               #status
```

Output

```
ORG-100023310
ORG-100023310
advanceCOR GmbH
[{'location-id': {'link': {'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100052061'}, 'id': 'LOC-100052061'}}, {'location-id': {'link': {'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100032442'}, 'id ': 'LOC-100032442'}}, 
{'location-id': {'link': {'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100042003'}, 'id': 'LOC-100042003'}}]
ACTIVE
ORG-100004261
ORG-100004261
Beacon Pharmaceuticals Limited
[{'location-id': {'link': {'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100005615'}, 'id': 'LOC-100005615'}}, {'location-id': {'link': {'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100000912'}, 'id': 'LOC-100000912'}}, {'location-id': {'link': {'href': 'https://v1/locations/LOC-100043831'}, 'id': 'LOC-100043831'}}]
ACTIVE
```